# How to Submit with html tags in Rails form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Have a textarea input form,

```
<%= f.text_area :body %>
```

in here, if i inserted texts with html tags

```
<p>text with p tag</p>
```

submit and paramter sends like this,

```
&lt;p&gt;this is param&lt;/p&gt;
```

how can i submit as plain text, not html entity?

Comment: This might be helpful http://richardyuwono.org/post/30443883596/rails-raw-htmlsafe-contentfor-wha

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is `raw` or `html_safe` method.

If you want to store string in DB with html tags - use `raw(string)` in controller or as `before_save` model callback.

Alternatively, you can just output this string as HTML with `raw`.

Note that `raw` is preferable, as you should't trust user input in general.

[raw](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/raw)